# cachegrind: set cache size

Tags: c++, linux, caching, cachegrind

I'm trying to test my program's performance on different cache sizes using cachegrind.
How do I set the cache size for the last level in the command? (I have read that the flag --LL should be used but it doesn't work. Can you please give me an example of the command?)

Thank you very much!